# Indexing over all possible functions in better than linear time

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics, time-complexity

Given two sets X and Y, the number of functions mapping X to Y is $\vert Y\vert^{\vert X \vert}$.

In particular I am interested in binary strings of relatively small length, e.g. 8.  There are $2^8$ (comprising set $B$) possible bit strings and $2^{2048}$ functions that map onto the same set (let's call the set of these $F$ ).  So I need 2048 bits to represent these functions uniquely.

My goal is to find a function, that given an arbitrary an arbitrary 2048 length bit string, will return the appropriate function from  the $F$.  I can imagine doing this with space on order $2^8$, and average time linear in $|F|$, using a hash table mapping $B\rightarrow B$ and some enumeration over mappings.

The question is, can I do better than this, especially with regard to the linear time (without of course just storing all functions)?

Comment: What do you mean by returning a function?  How do you represent a function?

Comment: Why $2^{2048}$? ($|X|=|Y|=2^8$).

Comment: @Vor: Calculate $|Y|^{|X|}$. :)

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: thanks for convincing my mind that 8*256 is not 1024!!! :-)

Comment: @Vor: Yeah, 8×256 is surprisingly large. :)

Comment: A function could be represented by any computable means.  E.g. as a simple table, or a function in any programming language.  By return a function I mean I want to find a function that maps bit strings (of 2048 length) to functions in F.

Comment: It is easier to just think about the natural numbers instead of the binary strings. Every function is just a ordered k tuple of integers from 0 to n-1. Now you can consider it as integers in base n. All you need is to implement all the simple bijections, which is nothing more than base conversion.

Comment: Just interpret the 2048-bit string as the 8-bit values of the function, listed in order (i.e., $f(0) \oplus f(1) \oplus \dots \oplus f(255)$, where $\oplus$ is concatenation).  To find $f(x)$, read off the 8 bits beginning at bit $8x$.